# How to match more than one labels in Prometheus alerts?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to send notifications either it has Level1 or Level2. But I'm not sure if Prometheus tries to find two of the labels at the same time, which is not the case. How can I do that?

```
- receiver: 'alert'
  match:
    severity: Level1
    severity: Level2
  group_wait: 10s
  continue: true
```

Update: severity: `Level1|Level2` didnt work.

Answer (score 5):

As explained [in the documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route), `match` of instruction must fulfill every entry. I am even surprised that your configuration works.

> A set of equality matchers an alert has to fulfill to match the node.

If you want to use a regex, uou can use `match_re`:

```
- receiver: 'alert'
  match_re:
    severity: Level1|Level2
  group_wait: 10s
  continue: true
```

Note that alertmanager (v0.22) introduced the usage of [`matchers`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#matcher) whose syntax reuses PromQL:

```
- receiver: 'alert'
  matchers: [ '{severity=~"Level1|Level2"}' ]
  group_wait: 10s
  continue: true
```

Which is much easier to write and explore in Prometheus GUI.